# bluetooth issues on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, bluetooth

After I've re-installed a complete new Ubuntu 20.04 (from ISO) the Bluetooth has stopped working. In order to save time I've bought a new USB dongle that is supposed to work with Linux. I see other customers reporting the dongle actually works fine with their Ubuntu 20.04, but I have no success so far.

Strangely I see no errors whatsoever, however it fails to detect any Bluetooth devices (for example the Bluetooth mouse I have on my desk)

I'm puzzled why it doesn't work, no idea what else I should try.

```
$> dmesg
[  513.869028] usb 2-4: new full-speed USB device number 10 using xhci_hcd
[  514.019491] usb 2-4: New USB device found, idVendor=0a5c, idProduct=21e8, bcdDevice= 1.12
[  514.019499] usb 2-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  514.019504] usb 2-4: Product: BCM20702A0
[  514.019508] usb 2-4: Manufacturer: Broadcom Corp
[  514.019511] usb 2-4: SerialNumber: 0019860032D1
[  514.135009] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 63
[  514.136010] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x07
[  514.152025] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM20702A
[  514.153102] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM20702A1 (001.002.014) build 0000
[  515.095015] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM20702A1 (001.002.014) build 1764
[  515.111045] Bluetooth: hci0: Broadcom Bluetooth Device

petrum@nuc ~ $ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 010: ID 0a5c:21e8 Broadcom Corp. BCM20702A0 Bluetooth 4.0

petrum@nuc ~ $ lsmod | grep -i blue
bluetooth             548864  41 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb,rfcomm
ecdh_generic           16384  2 bluetooth
```

Some other commands I've tried:

```
petrum@nuc ~ $ sudo bluetoothctl
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# scan on
Discovery started
[bluetooth]# list
Controller 00:19:86:00:32:D1 nuc [default]
[bluetooth]# devices
[bluetooth]# quit

petrum@nuc ~ $ rfkill list
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

I started to believe  something is wrong with my installation of Ubuntu, as I've tried a total of 3x different Bluetooth USB dongles, more or less with the same results.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

Did you enable Bluetooth under Setting?

Check if these packages are installed: "bluez-utils" and "libopenobex1"

---

else try this 2 commands:

```
sudo rmmod btusb
sudo modprobe btusb
```

Comment: Can't find any package with "bluez-utils"